# Only StartCoroutine of Update on child prefab functions

Tags: unity

I have a script attached to a prefab.  That prefab attached to a child and I want it to rotate the root transform.

The Update of the script executes nothing but the Coroutine of a class I wrote.
Attached is the hierarchy of the outside and inside of playmode as well as the script on the prefab and the class.

From the Editor, Not on Playmode.
[image: From the Editor, Not on Playmode.]

and in Plamode
[image: in PlayMode.]

**uiTurnTileScropt.cs**

```
//THIS SCRIPT IS CURRENTLY ON THE CCW PREFAB

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class uiTurnTileScript : MonoBehaviour {
public float rotSpeed = 7.0f;
public float degree = 36.0f;
public float waitTime = .3f;
private bool rotate = false;
private Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.identity;
BlockButton clickTapBlocked ;

void Start(){
    clickTapBlocked = gameObject.AddComponent<BlockButton>();
    clickTapBlocked.bttnName = "clickTap";
    clickTapBlocked.setFalse();
}
void Update () {
    Debug.Log (transform.name);
    if(Input.GetButtonDown (clickTapBlocked.bttnName) && (!clickTapBlocked.blocked)  ){
        Debug.Log("MouseDown");
        StartCoroutine(clickTapBlocked.forTime(waitTime)); 
        newRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (transform.root.rotation.eulerAngles.z - degree, Vector3.forward);
        rotate = true;
    }
    RotateSetAmount ();
}
void RotateSetAmount(){
    Debug.Log ("In Rotate function");
    if (rotate){
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.root.rotation, newRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotSpeed);
        if (transform.root.rotation.eulerAngles.z <  newRotation.eulerAngles.z){
            transform.root.rotation = newRotation;
            rotate = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

and the referenced class **BlockButton** in uiTurnTileScript.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

/*  This class is more intuitive if you name thie instance created ("buttonValue" +     blocked)
 *  Example: for a button in the Input Project settings with a string of Fire1  I     would name the instance fire1Blocked
 *  Declare with your other variables 

    BlockButton fire1Blocked

void Start(){
    //
    Fire1Blocked = gameObject.AddComponent<BlockButton>();
    Fire1Blocked.bttnName = "Fire1Blocked";
    Fire1Blocked.setFalse();
}
 */  
public class BlockButton  : MonoBehaviour  {

public string bttnName;
public bool blocked = false;

public bool setFalse(){
    blocked = false;
    return blocked;
}

public bool setTrue(){
    blocked = true;
    return blocked;
}

public IEnumerator forTime(float duration){
    Debug.Log ("I was called");
    float dur = duration;
    blocked = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(dur);
    blocked = false;
}
}
```

In my output,no matter what I click, I get nothing but the code from the BlockButton Instance.  No debug from the Update() happens but the coroutine happens.  I am not understanding how that happens and how to implement this properly.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you don't see the Debug call in Update but you Do see the Debug call in your coroutine?

Comment: Thats how I know the coroutine is called.  "I was called" is the only thing that shows up in console.  Neither debug is shown from the output.

Comment: I tried Debug from Start and still nothing.  I assume that the class BlockButton is being called independently of the uiTurnTile.